# Play Framework1.2.3 Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed

Tags: java, playframework

I get this message in the console when I run a Play app.

```
06:08:08,069 INFO  ~ Starting D:\projects\play1.2.3\test
06:08:08,623 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
06:08:08,737 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start)    ...
06:08:31,229 INFO  ~ Application 'test' is now started !
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed
...
```

I don't have any problems running the app but this "Debugger failed" message keeps comimg out and it just bugs me.

This happens even if I create a clean project.
ports 8000 and 9000 are open.

System is
Java 1.6.0_24
Play 1.2.3
Windows7 64bit

How could I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sorry this had nothing to do with play.

There seems to be some other connection coming from my router accessing port 8000 and that was the problem.

If I change the jpda.port to something other than 8000 the message doesn't show.

Comment: How do you change the jdpa port in Android Studio ?