# Play Framework 2.1.3 Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I get this message in the console when I run a Play.

```
C:\Users\Daniel\desenvolvimento\Sistemas>play debug
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >POST /setwindo< - expect
ed >JDWP-Handshake<
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >POST /setwindo< - expect
ed >JDWP-Handshake<
```

I don't have any problems running the app but this "Debugger failed" message keeps comimg out and it just bugs me.

This happens even if I create a clean project.

Play 2.1.3
Windows7 64bit

How could I get rid of this message?

Comment: have you tried changing port

Comment: Looks to me like something is trying to talk HTTP with your debug port 9999

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play Framework1.2.3 Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348609/play-framework1-2-3-debugger-failed-to-attach-handshake-failed)